# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'element'

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, nonetype

why in the code below when printing head.element inside the while loop I dont get any error
but the same code print code outside the loop get me an error?

```
class node:
  def __init__(self, element):
        self.element = element
        self.next = None


head = None

node1 = node(1)
node2 = node(2)

head = node1
node1.next = node2

while head != None:
    print(head.element)
    head = head.next

print(head.element)
```

Comment: Because you're looping *until* `head == None`. So once the loop stops your next line is attempting to print `None.element`

Comment: @xxmira, if an answer worked for you, you should accept it to mark it as a working one. Welcome to Stack Overflow anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is raised by your last line of code:

```
print(head.element)
```

when/if the flow reaches the line above, the `head` variable is `None`, since the `while` loop ends only when `head == None`.

```
while head != None:
    print(head.element)
    head = head.next # The last time this will return None
```

Answer (score 1):

In last iteration while loop, the head was asing `None` and you try to print the property element of class None.